# Highlighting non-local variables in VS Code Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The VS Code syntax highlighter is able to highlight unused variables in a function body.

I'm looking for the "converse": variables that are used, but not parameters or defined inside the function. Instead they're defined somewhere else in the same module.

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(5)
def f():
    print(x[:, np.newaxis])
```

In this snippet `x` would be highlighted as a free variable, but preferably not `np.newaxis` (which is defined to be `None`).

Is it possible to do this using VS Code?

Comment: according to your rules `np` would be highlighted too, `np` is a variable in global scope, it is bad practice to use global variables in functions (if other solutions are possible), you can only use the function in a particular place

Comment: @rioV8 1) If such a feature exists, it could define exclusions on things like imported modules 2) related advice is no replacement for an answer.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question

Comment: @julaine a comment is not an answer

Comment: @rioV8 You are right. I did not mean to say your advice is inappropriate. I understood your comment to imply that the question does not need an answer because the underlying problem of global variables should be solved instead, but you did not say that.

Comment: @rioV8: Yeah, that's why I added `np` to the snippet. The highlighter should know what a module is. I agree that it is bad practice to add globals to functions, that's why I would like the hightligther to bring my attention to it.

Comment: then don't use globals in functions, or give them a specific name prefix `g_myvar`, VSC will signal if you want to modify globals if you have them

Comment: Sometimes it's the right thing to do, e.g. closures. I would just like it brought to my attention.